# Clone option is not available in VM Virtual Box

Tags: virtualbox, clone

I can't find the 'Clone' option in `Oracle VM Virtual Box` in Ubuntu 12.04 is there any option to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the command line:

```
VBoxManage clonevm          <uuid|vmname>
```

This command creates a full or linked copy of an existing virtual machine.

The clonevm subcommand takes at least the name of the virtual machine which should be cloned. The following additional settings can be used to further configure the clone VM operation:

```
                            [--snapshot <uuid>|<name>]
                            [--mode machine|machineandchildren|all]
                            [--options link|keepallmacs|keepnatmacs|
                                       keepdisknames]
                            [--name <name>]
                            [--groups <group>, ...]
                            [--basefolder <basefolder>]
                            [--uuid <uuid>]
                            [--register]
```

useful links:

- [HOWTO: Cloning a complete VM (not only the VDI)](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?t=9583)
- [VBoxManage clonevm](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#vboxmanage-clonevm)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the VM you are trying to clone is powered off. In the GUI right click on the VM you want to clone and should the clone option.

Comment: Done the same... Its not there ... honestly .. !